# Stubbing Grape helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-grape, ruby-mocha

I have Rails app with Grape API.

The interface is done with Backbone and Grape API provides it all data.

All it returns is user-specific stuff, so i need reference to currently logged in user.

Simplified version looks like this:

API initialization:

```
module MyAPI
  class API < Grape::API
    format :json

    helpers MyAPI::APIHelpers

    mount MyAPI::Endpoints::Notes
  end
end
```

Endpoint:

```
module MyAPI
  module Endpoints
    class Notes < Grape::API
      before do
        authenticate!
      end

      # (...) Api methods
    end
  end
end
```

API helper:

```
module MyAPI::APIHelpers
  # @return [User]
  def current_user
    env['warden'].user
  end

  def authenticate!
    unless current_user
      error!('401 Unauthorized', 401)
    end
  end
end
```

So, as you can see, i get the current user from Warden and it works fine. But the problem is with testing.

```
describe MyAPI::Endpoints::Notes do
  describe 'GET /notes' do
    it 'it renders all notes when no keyword is given' do
      Note.expects(:all).returns(@notes)
      get '/notes'
      it_presents(@notes)
    end
  end
end
```

How can I stub helpers's method *current_user* with some specific user?

I tried:

- setting env/request, but it doesn't exist before calling *get* method.
- stubbing MyAPI::APIHelpers#current_user method with Mocha
- stubbing MyAPI::Endpoints::Notes.any_instance.stub with Mocha

Edit:
At the moment, it's stubbed this way:

spec:

```
  # (...)
  before :all do
    load 'patches/api_helpers'
    @user = STUBBED_USER
  end
  # (...)
```

spec/patches/api_helpers.rb:

```
STUBBED_USER = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
module MyAPI::APIHelpers
  def current_user
    STUBBED_USER
  end
end
```

But it's definitely not the answer :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comments mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/intridea/grape/issues/227) should help you, It's how even Grape tests it's helpers,

https://github.com/intridea/grape/blob/master/spec/grape/endpoint_spec.rb#L475
(If the code is not there on the same line due to changes, just do a ctrl+f & look for helpers)

Here's some code from the same file

```
it 'resets all instance variables (except block) between calls' do
  subject.helpers do
    def memoized
      @memoized ||= params[:howdy]
    end
  end

  subject.get('/hello') do
    memoized
  end

  get '/hello?howdy=hey'
  last_response.body.should == 'hey'
  get '/hello?howdy=yo'
  last_response.body.should == 'yo'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Option 1

The [recommended](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/pull/397#issuecomment-48756994) way is to use `Grape::Endpoint.before_each`:

```rb
context 'when user is logged in' do
  before do
    Grape::Endpoint.before_each do |endpoint|
      allow(endpoint).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
    end
  end

  after { Grape::Endpoint.before_each nil }
end
```

But this is quite verbose. It can live in a [shared context](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context), but you can't pass `user` as a parameter explicitly so you'd end up with:

```rb
let(:user) { create(:user) }
# ...
include_context 'signed in user'
```

##### Option 2

My preferred way is a more RSpec-like stubbing:

```rb
# helper
module AuthHelper
  def current_user
    # ...
  end
end

# api
module API
  module V1
    class Auth < Grape::API
      helpers AuthHelper
    end
  end
end

# spec
before do
  allow_any_instance_of(AuthHelper).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
end
```

##### Option 3

You can also [define helpers](https://github.com/dblock/grape/blob/ec27c81e3d643696ef6e96d1611c086b623b7887/spec/grape/api_spec.rb#L913-L921):

```rb
API::V1::User.helpers do
  def current_user
    user
  end
end
```